# Prevent dialog to be opened multiple times when resuming activity

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-dialog

In my Android application, in order to ask the user if he/she wants to resume a current game, I display a dialog saying "Do you want to resume current game? Yes - No" on the main game activity.

The thing is that if I resume various times this activity without answering the dialog, then I get several dialogs, on top of each other, which is obviously not my goal.

I could easily avoid this behavior using a Boolean var, but I was wondering if the Dialog class had a kind of option preventing to be duplicated or something of the kind.

Comment: you can try dialog.isShowing()

Comment: when you exit app and open again, the activity is restarted and, i assume, because of your code formation, dialog is restarted again, but maybe been never closed before.. maybe if you put onPause(){ Dialog.dismiss();} it couldhelp your issue

Comment: `isFinishing()` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use singleton pattern, could be roughly like this:

```
Dialog myDialog = null;


public void showDialog() {
    if(myDialog == null) {
        /* show your dialog here... */
        myDialog = ...
    }
}


public void hideDialog() {
    if(myDialog != null) {
        /* hide your dialog here... */
        myDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam Am facing same problem but am using alertdialogbuilder to create dialog, any solution..??

Answer (score 5):

```
private Dialog mDialog;

private void showDialog(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message);

    // Dismiss any old dialog.
    if (mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    // Show the new dialog.
    mDialog = dialogBuilder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather then doing hacks or using booleans you can use [the method given by google itself](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing())

```
public boolean isShowing ()
```

it Returns a boolean value
Whether the dialog is currently showing.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered such a problem when I tried to override the `onDismiss()` method without `super.onDismiss(dialog);`

It turns out I deleted `super.onDismiss(dialog)` and because of this, the dialogs were duplicated

Back added, the error disappeared.

I hope someone will help

Answer (score 1):

Check Dialog already showing or not

```
private Dialog mDialog;

private void showDialog(String title, String message) {
    //stop multiple dialog window
    if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        return;
    }
    
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message);

    dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isAdded() method,

Kotlin example:

```
view.button.setOnClickListener({
            if (!dialog.isAdded) {
                dialogShow(dialog)
            }
        })
```

and somewhere in the fragment or activity

```
private fun dialogShow(dialog: DialogFragment?) {
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = (context as MyActivity).fragmentManager
        dialog?.show( fragmentManager,TAG)
    }
```